# Symfony 2 where to put view logic

Tags: model-view-controller, symfony

What is the best strategy if you find your controller's code not readable and messed up because of heavy view logic? Use helper, service or something else?

Comment: Your controller should call services and expose the results to the view.

Comment: How to organize this? Single UtilityService with lots of methods, many small services, or maybe use entities own services (ProductService) for presentation purposes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best practice is to have all the logic encapsulated in **services**. The code will be more decoupled and easy to maintenance. Decide between small services or big ones is your responsibility, but the best practice is to have services with one defined functionality, moderate size, maintainable and testable

If the logic is to get data from a form, or is related to a form, the best option is use a **handler** to encapsulate the form logic. You can see a live example of handlers in [FOSUserBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/tree/master/Form/Handler).